# How to know the total license in Salesforce in apex?

Tags: apex, soql, user, licenses, userlicense

I have scenario to find the remaining license in salesforce.I have found the count of used licenses by below query

```
Integer licenses =[SELECT COUNT() FROM User WHERE Profile.UserLicense.Name = 'Force.com - Free' AND IsActive = true];
```

Now i need to the remaining "Force.com - Free" licenses available in my org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the UserLicense table to get at this data:

```
UserLicense ul = [select TotalLicenses, UsedLicenses from userlicense where Name = 'Force.com - Free'];
```

From there, you need to subtract usedlicenses from totallicenses to get the number of free licenses.

Alternatively, use one query:

```
AggregateResult res =
    [SELECT COUNT(Id), MAX(Profile.UserLicense.TotalLicenses) total, 
            MAX(Profile.UserLicense.UsedLicenses) used 
     FROM User 
     WHERE Profile.UserLicense.Name = 'Force.com - Free' AND 
           IsActive = true GROUP BY Profile.UserLicense.Name];
```